# adding Headers on a href

Tags: html

I have some links on a html page that I use to open a new tab and display the required page using something like:

```
<a href="[yourlink]" target="_blank" style="target-new: tab;">Google</a>
```

But I'm trying to figure is there a way I can set a Header on the link, I want to set the Accept Header?

Comment: what you mean by header?

Comment: Request Headers: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, etc.

Comment: Not possible. You can bind a javascript function to the link and send the request with headers in it.

Comment: you may pass some query parameters `?param1=value1` and handle them server side...

Comment: also I never saw that `target-new`... cannot find it on caniuse, and this page says it is not very supported xD https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answers folks.